# Joining two tables: Provided/Budget

Tags: sql-server, join, percentage

I have written two programs; One which sum the total cost for services provided and one which pulls in the projected budgets for the services. The budgets can be renewed once a year or every six months.   I’m having trouble joining to the programs together so I can calculate the % of budgets used for each **waver service** by **month**.

### Projected Budget Program

```
SELECT 
ChildID,
WAIVER_SERVICES,
START_DT,
END_DT,
RATE_PER_UNIT_OF_SERVICE,
PROJECTED_COST_PER_MONTH
FROM [ECMS_BACKUP].[dbo].[B2H_DSP]
where CLT_NBR=10177
and WAIVER_SERVICES NOT IN (1,10,11,12) 
and WAIVER_PROGRAM=2
```

**The Budget data set I bring back looks something like this:**

```
  CREATE TABLE Budget  (
    ChildID int,
   WAIVER_SERVICES      int,
    START_DT date, 
    END_DT date,
    RATE_PER_UNIT_OF_SERVICE int(30),
    PROJECTED_COST_PER_MONTH 
    ); 
INSERT INTO Budget VALUES 

(10177, 2,  '06/01/12', '06/01/13', 13.23,  158.76),
(10177, 3,  '06/01/12', '06/01/13', 13.23,  211.68),
(10177, 5,  '06/01/12', '06/01/13', 19.45,  466.8),
(10177, 8,  '06/01/12', '06/01/13', 236.7,  473.4),
(10177, 9,  '06/01/12', '06/01/13', 19.55,  312.8),
(10177, 2,  '06/03/13', '06/03/14', 13.23,  158.76),
(10177, 3,  '06/03/13', '06/03/14', 13.23,  211.68),
(10177, 5,  '06/03/13', '06/03/14', 19.45,  466.8),
(10177, 6,  '06/03/13', '06/03/14', 55.68,  222.72),
(10177, 8,  '06/03/13', '06/03/14', 236.7,  473.4),
(10177, 9,  '06/03/13', '06/03/14', 19.55,  312.8)
```

**Notice the START_DT and END_DT are not set set monthly but yearly.**

## Services Provided Program

```
select 
a.ChildID,
b.WAIVER_SERVICES,
 month(a.DOSStart) as Month, 
 YEAR(a.DOSStart) as Year,
sum(b.RATE_AMOUNT)as total
from 
    [ECMS_BACKUP].[dbo].[B2H_SummaryForms]a
left JOIN ECMS_BACKUP.dbo.B2H_RATE b ON a.RateCode=b.RATE_CODE
where DOSStart>='2013-01-01' AND DOSStart<'2013-06-30'
group by ChildID, month(a.DOSStart), YEAR(a.DOSStart),WAIVER_SERVICES
order by childid,  month(a.DOSStart), YEAR(a.DOSStart),WAIVER_SERVICES
```

**The Services Provided data set I bring back looks something like this:**

```
 CREATE TABLE Provided  (
   ChildID int,
   WAIVER_SERVICES      int,
   Month int, 
    Year int,
   total  int,
    ); 
INSERT INTO Provided VALUES 
('10177',   3,  3,  2013,   13.23),
('10177',   5,  3,  2013,   77.8),
('10177',   8,  3,  2013,   236.7),
('10177',   9,  3,  2013,   19.55),
('10177',   3,  4,  2013,   13.23),
('10177',   5,  4,  2013,   19.45),
('10177',   5,  5,  2013,   19.45),
('10177',   8,  5,  2013,   236.7),
('10177',   9,  5,  2013,   19.55),
('10177',   5,  6,  2013,   19.45),
('10177',   8,  6,  2013,   236.7),
('10177',   3,  8,  2012,   17.2),
('10177',   3,  10, 2012,   13.23),
('10177',   8,  10, 2012,   473.4),
('10177',   9,  10, 2012,   19.55),
('10177',   2,  11, 2012,   13.23),
('10177',   3,  11, 2012,   13.23)
```

Again, I am have trouble joining these two data sets to get something that looks like this

```
     ChildID  WAIVER_SERVICES Month/Year services_provided Budget % used      

     10177         3             12/2012          125         125   100% 

     10177         3              1/2013          75          125    60%        

     10177         3              2/2013          100         175    57% 

     10177         9              1/2013          50           50    100%            

     10177         9              5/2013          800         950    84%
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: your results don't have any column names.  how can we know what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your result set contains exact expected values  or not. If it is just a sample value then you can join two table like -

```
 SELECT b.ChildID,
        b.WAIVER_SERVICES,
        CAST(p.[Month] AS VARCHAR(20)) + '/' + CAST(p.[Year] AS VARCHAR(20)) 
        'Month/YEAR',
        SUM(p.total) services_provided,
        CAST(b.RATE_PER_UNIT_OF_SERVICE AS FLOAT) / CAST(b.PROJECTED_COST_PER_MONTH AS FLOAT) 
        * 100 'Budget % use'
 FROM   Budget b
INNER JOIN Provided p ON  p.ChildID = b.ChildID AND p.WAIVER_SERVICES = b.WAIVER_SERVICES
 GROUP BY
        b.ChildID,
        b.WAIVER_SERVICES,
        CAST(p.[Month] AS VARCHAR(20)) + '/' + CAST(p.[Year] AS VARCHAR(20)),
        CAST(b.RATE_PER_UNIT_OF_SERVICE AS FLOAT) / CAST(b.PROJECTED_COST_PER_MONTH AS FLOAT) * 100
```